# React styled component causes build error in production, but runs fine in development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, build

I am having a weird problem with my code, I have a styled component div that wraps around another component like this:

```
<ContentWidget>
  <BookDay />
</ContentWidget>
```

(Bookday returns an empty div so this should not be a problem)

My styled component ContentWidget is an empty styled component div and is declared like this:

```
const ContentWidget = styled.div``;
```

The weird thing is I have more contentwidgets filled with content that load other components inside of my webapp. All imports are fine because it works in development perfectly fine. But whenever I run `npm run build` I get the following error message in my console.

> ERROR in ./app/containers/Dashboard/Dashboard.js 41:18 Module parse
>   failed: Unexpected keyword 'var' (41:18) You may need an appropriate
>   loader to handle this file type. | import ForegroundBlob from
>   "basicComponents/ForegroundBlob/ForegroundBlob"; | import
>   ForegroundBlobWrapper from
>   "basicComponents/ForegroundBlob/ForegroundBlobWrapper";
>
> > import BookDay, { var _ref = | /*#**PURE***/ | _jsx(ContentWidget, {}, void 0, _jsx(BookDay, {})); } from "components/BookDay/BookDay"; 
> >     @ ./app/containers/PracticePage/PracticePage.js 40:0-55 58:5-14  @
> >     ./app/containers/PracticePage/Loadable.js  @
> >     ./app/containers/App/App.js  @ ./app/app.js  @ multi
> >     ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/ie11.js ./app/app.js

I found out that whenever I just change the  tags with a standard div tag, it seems to build like it should. I have never been as confused as I have been now.

Comment: Could you show your implementation of BookDay please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay so I found out myself after a little bit of debugging.

It seems that the `"@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements",` babel plugin messes with styled components.

Comment: Maybe late, what is the solution here?

Comment: I did not find another solution than to delete the plugin, because I didn't need it myself.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me as well. But i'm not sure about the consequences on my project. 

Comment: Luckily for me it didn't have (any) consequences, so hopefully it is the same for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected keyword 'var' (13:23) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I am unclear on exactly why, but moving styled components I was using into the file where I was using them, rather than importing them from a different file, resolved the problem. It does in fact seem to be some sort of issue with how `"@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements"` deals with `styled-components`; may have to do something with circular dependencies.